# Глюк в Sublime Text с LiveStyle

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

У меня установлены LiveStyle, Hayaku, Emmet. Когда подключён LiveStyle, и я начинаю что-то писать в CSS-коде, код копируется и вставляется в конец. Удаляю копию — удаляется оригинал, код вставляется не пойми куда. Кто ещё сталкивался с таким поведением LiveStyle?

Comment: У меня просто копируется CSS второй раз снизу от основного и меняются переносы..
Что делать с этим - не знаю...